join dependent equal attributes arrays php
I'm trying to group this way without success, I looked for something similar but I can't find it. your support please
I have the following result:
Array (
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [almacen] => ALMACEN 001 
    [vendedor] => CHRISTOFER 
    [total] => 15161.42 ) 

[1] => stdClass Object ( 
    [almacen] => ALMACEN 005 
    [vendedor] => DAVID 
    [total] => 801.00 ) 

[2] => stdClass Object ( 
    [almacen] => ALMACEN 001 
    [vendedor] => DAVID 
    [total] => 15350.77 ) 

[3] => stdClass Object ( 
    [almacen] => ALMACEN 005 
    [vendedor] => EVA 
    [total] => 122839.22 ) 

[4] => stdClass Object ( 
    [almacen] => ALMACEN 001 
    [vendedor] => OWNER 
    [total] => 632.00 )
)

what you are looking to obtain:
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [almacen] => ALMACEN 001 
    [vendedor] => [CHRISTOFER, DAVID, OWNER]
    [total] => [15161.42, 15350.77, 632.00])
    
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
    [almacen] => ALMACEN 005 
    [vendedor] => [DAVID, EVA]
    [total] => [801.00, 122839.22])

without success
foreach ($staff_sales as $item1) {
    foreach ($staff_sales as $item2) {
        if($item1->almacen == $item2->almacen){
            $it->almacen = $item2->almacen;
            $it->vendedor[] = $item2->vendedor;
            $it->total[] = $item2->total;
        }
    }
}

